# Put limit on wordpress custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to limit WordPress custom fields where I am fetching through a loop and I want only first two results. I am not very familiar with PHP.

Here is the code below I am using,

```
<?php 
  $gallery_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'gallery_data', true );
  if ( isset( $gallery_data['image_url'] ) ) {
    for( 
      $i = 0; 
      $i < count( $gallery_data['image_url'] ); 
      $i++ ) {
?>

<div class="clearfix audio-block">
  <span class="play-btn in-spa" play-url="<?php esc_html_e( $gallery_data['image_url'][$i] ); ?>">
    <a href=""> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></a>
  </span>

  <span class="recite-nam in-spa"> 
    <?php esc_html_e( $gallery_data['text_url'][$i] );  ?>
  </span>
</div>


<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want the first two results, you can change your `for($i = 0; $i < count( $gallery_data['image_url'] ); $i++ ) ` by `for($i = 0; $i < count( $gallery_data['image_url'] ) && $i < 2; $i++ )`. That way, if you have only one image in your gallery, it will show only this image, if you have 2 or more images in this gallery it will stop at 2.

Comment: thank you let me try this :)

Comment: Yes, It works. Thank you so much @Julqas

Comment: No problem ! Have fun with PHP !

Comment: Great Job. Thanks again :)